# how do i create donate buttons using paypal premier account?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, donations

how do i create donate buttons using paypal premier account?. i couldn't find donation button creation link, how can i do that?.
Is there any special procedure to get donation button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

donate button option does not appears if user logged in, so create one without loggedin and change that code to match to registered users code like emailid and so on. But i dont know this is right or wrong. I used this method for one project and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I got to it through [this link](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_donate-intro-outside) and can see Donation as an option in the "Accept Payments For" dropdown.

Comment: i can view "donations" options in accept payments when i am not logged in. after logged into account i couldn't view "donations" option

Comment: I can create donation button by your method without logged in (just by giving emailid). shall i receive donations?

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs this, then you'll find the buttons under the `Merchant Services` menu item in your profile. Click on the menu item and then you'll see "Create Payment Button for your website" in that page. Clicking that link, you'll be able to create your button (any type).